# Laravel mostrar articulos ordenados

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Cómo puedo obtener una cantidad de artículos ordenados del más nuevo al más antiguo (actualmente me aparece del más antiguo al más nuevo) en laravel 5.4

en el controlador, la función de la página principal home es así:

```
public function home(){

      $blogs = Blog::paginate(7);

      return view('welcome',[

        'blogs' => $blogs,

      ]);
```

Comment: ¿El modelo blog utiliza el timestamp `created_at`?

Comment: class Blog extends Model
{
    protected $guarded = [];
}

Comment: Ese es el modelo Blog

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si el modelo utiliza el timestamp `created_at`, entonces lo puedes ordenar de forma descendente por dicho campo:

```
$blogs = Blog::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->paginate(7);
```

En caso que no utilices dichos timestamp, asumiendo que tengas una columna id que incremente automáticamente, entonces lo podrías hacer así:

```
$blogs = Blog::orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(7);
```

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias, me funcionaron ambas respuestas